# Secure link between two peers without certificates?

Tags: java, security, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am writing software in Java that will run on Android, Windows, Linux and OSX and want the devices to all talk to each other securely.

My initial thought was just to use a asymmetric algorithm (eg. RSA) and share the public keys manually. Then sessions would be encrypted just using RSA. I hit problems with this due to buffer size, then I read about CBC etc and the problems of data leakage if some form of XOR of data was not performed.

So...I looked at using AES/CBC/{padding}. Initially this sounded good: just share the key, an IV and away we go.

But these apps all talk to each other in both directions at any time, so keeping the IV in sync did not seem possible, resulting in a new IV being sent with every message. Not a big deal, but one of the advantages of AES over RSA is data size, and now I'm going to be adding 32 bytes to every message. Though I guess keeping a 'receiver' and a 'sender' Cipher would probably work.

Now I am back to considering alternatives, and trying to avoid too much roll-your-own.

Is there any substantial reason not to use RSA and CBC (or similar) done manually? ie. break data into chunks, pad as necessary, and encrypt with RSA, doing whatever XOR strategy seems most reliable.

Is there a better was to keep secure and trusted comms between pairs of peers without creating an SSL CA? Or, is there a way of hooking into the certificate verifier so that I can use my pre-shared public keys to validate the peer connections?

Any other suggestions/examples for best/simple multi-platform peer-peer secure comms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look into implementing a [hybrid cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem). If I can guess your knowledge about the subject correctly you should *really* be using a pre-existing one like TLS, or DTLS, as you're not going to design a cryptographically safe protocol out of the blue.

Note that the certificates are required to create a PKI, and the asymmetric crypto of course comes with it. You should however only have to use the asymmetric crypto during the *handshake* which includes the initial authentication and session key negotiation.

Comment: +1 for `you're not going to design a cryptographically safe protocol out of the blue.`. OP, please don´t overestimate your own knowledge if user data is on the line.

Comment: Just to note: I've seen bad protocols being designed by international standardization bodies, smart card/HSM vendors and - of course - me. This stuff is *tricky*.

Comment: Indeed, +1 for the diplomatic wording of the response.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that the major reason not to roll-my-own (RSA with CBC) is that it's hard to get right, but that technically, it's probably an OK solution?

Comment: No, RSA with CBC doesn't really exist. Using only RSA for the cipher is not going to fly, and neither is just CBC. Technically it is *not* a good solution.

Comment: ...and forgot to say, my AES atempt was a hybrid system but got bogged down for the reasons outlined. Looking into TLS with a custom Keystore now (I want the keys stored in the app database), but Android is not very helpful in producing certificates without using 2.8MB of Bouncy Castle...

Comment: I know it's a pedantic point, but I'd really like to understand why RSA/CBC would not work. RSA with a 2048 bit key does 117 bytes at a time, it's trivial to implement CBC on top of that (assuming it's necessary), and it's purely for cooperating apps. But I do get it's silly to be going this pass alone..it's just I'm curious about the "why" part...

Comment: There is no such thing as RSA/CBC. CBC is a mode of operation for block ciphers where the plaintext is the same size as the ciphertext. You would have to define it first. RSA is one of the least efficient operations you'll ever encounter, you really should not run it in CBC mode. CBC mode does not provide integrity or authentication. Finally, 2048 / 8 - 11 = 245, not 117. That would be for 1024 bit keys.

Comment: Thanks for the answer(s); and yeah, not 117, but I don't seem to be able to edit my comments. I should proof-read earlier, I guess.